# how can i access Rational Team Concert source code from a 4.0.7 server using eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I'm using Neon, and the p2 repository for rtc 4.0.7/ eclipse 4.2 does not show any compatible items.  Where can i get 4.0.7 for 4.6/Neon?

Message when i add the p2 site to "Help=>Install New Software..." is "There are no categorised items"

Alternatively, is it possible to run the RTC Client as a seperate app to eclipse, but have it sync the files in my eclipse workspace?  Sharing the workspace does not work.

Answer (score 1):

See "[System Requirements for CLM 2012: Rational Team Concert 4.0,](https://jazz.net/library/article/811)", section "[Eclipse IDE (RTC Eclipse Client)](https://jazz.net/library/article/811#mozTocId727440) "

RTC4 has no compatibility with *recent* Eclipse 4.x: as the [OP dan carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692626/dan-carter) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607006/how-can-i-access-rational-team-concert-source-code-from-a-4-0-7-server-using-ecl/39614804#comment66563306_39614804), the [RTC 4.0.7](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.7?p=allDownloads) page shows only a RTC Client for Eclipse 4.2.x IDE.

You can use the RTC Eclipse Client, but I would advise for the (Eclipse 3.x-based workspace) to remain separate from your Eclipse 4.6 workspace  though.

Comment: Thanks i guess it's a no go then.  That's the setup i have at the moment, one eclipse workspace to do development in, and a second for doing checkins and updates with RTC, then a batch script to rsync/robocopy between the two.  Only matter of time until i run the script in the wrong direction and blow away all my updates though.  If only we used git or subversion life would be so much simpler...

Comment: Minor correction, RTC4 does work with 4.x, where x=2 but not where x=6. Not sure about the versions inbetween.  See https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.7?p=allDownloads.  Would be good to know the latest that does support it, i don't mind going backwards a couple of eclipse releases

Comment: @dancarter OK, I have updated the answer accordingly.